# When I create a file in my user directory it displays on my desktop directory. can anyone help me?

Tags: linux, terminal, directory, desktop, mv

I tried to change the name of my desktop directory but I did something wrong. Now when I create a file in the user directory the file shows up on my desktop. I think that I changed the name of my desktop for my user directory.
anyone can help me to fix this problem?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

what's the return of `cd $HOME ; pwd` and `cd $HOME/Desktop ; pwd` ?

verify if the `$HOME/Desktop` is really a folder or an symbolic link to your $HOME or other folder. To do that execute `cd $HOME ; ls -la | grep ^l` if Desktop appears in list you turned the desktop folder into an symbolic link.